# How to do panning in Unity?

Tags: unity-game-engine, rotation, pan

I am a beginner in Unity and I created a 3D app in Unity.
For rotate, I'm rotating the camera around the 3d model.
For pan, if I move the 3d model, I've to keep a track of the coordinates (x,y,z). But if I move the camera, since LookAt() is implemented in the rotate function, it doesn't look like the pan gesture is executed (while shifting from rotating and panning).
Can someone please suggest a solution for this problem?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to pan with the object, you can do so using vector mathematics.

Example:

```
new Vector3 lookAt = ...;
new Vector3 offset = ...;

cameraTransform.LookAt(lookAt + offset);
```

if you want to change between the motions of panning and rotation, you can use a statemachine for that.

```
switch (state)
{
    case CHANGEPAN:
        // do something
        break;
    case CHANGEROT:
        // do something
        break;
}
```

whilst panning, if you don't want to rotate the camera at all, you'll need to do an equivalent translation to the cameras position. You can do that also with vector mathematics, since position in the transform is just a Vector3.